# When Google Map SDK iOS is used in Xode7.0, it'll be an error

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, sdk, bitcode

Everyone. Thank you very much.

I was using Google Map API in iOS.

It was used in X-Code 7.0 this time.

It's and is failed as follows.

What is the cause?

Would there be a countermeasure?

BITCODE succeeds in a build in NO.
I'd like to make it a bundle by Apple Watch correspondence, so I have to make BITCODE YES and am in trouble.
Thank you.

pod log

Ainetmakoto-no-MacBook-Pro:XcodeSorce ainetmakoto$ pod try GoogleMaps    Updating spec repositories
CocoaPods 0.39.0.beta.4 is available. To update use:
`gem install cocoapods --pre` [!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.
For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG    for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

Trying GoogleMaps Opening    '/private/var/folders/kz/m2sdcgh56wl4kpchk96g7kw40000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/GoogleMaps/GoogleMapsSDKDemos/SDKDemos.xcodeproj' Ainetmakoto-no-MacBook-Pro:XcodeSorce ainetmakoto$

A build of a sample isn't made of an error.

[image]

ld: '/var/folders/kz/m2sdcgh56wl4kpchk96g7kw40000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/GoogleMaps/GoogleMapsSDKDemos/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(GMSCachedTile.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 3):

its work for me :

- In **iOS 9**, Apple has made a change to the handling of URL schemes. Now
  you need to add "**LSApplicationQueriesSchemes**" key in plist and then
  add URLScheme you want to call & set **Enable bitcode** = **NO** in build settings tab

```html
   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key> 
   <array>
         <string>comgooglemaps</string> 
   </array>
```

Note: lack of Bitcode support still present in **GoogleMaps iOS SDK Version 1.10.5**.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is related to the lack of Bitcode support in Google Maps SDK for iOS, which is being tracked in the following feature request: 
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8219

The only solution until Google releases SDK with Bitcode support, is to set BITCODE to NO and to add "**LSApplicationQueriesSchemes**" key in plist, with the URLScheme you want to call:

```
   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key> 
   <array>
         <string>comgooglemaps</string> 
   </array>
```

Note: lack of Bitcode support still present in **GoogleMaps iOS SDK Version 1.10.5**.